# Do I have to maintain a strong reference to an NSURLSessionDataTask with completion handler?

Tags: memory-management, nsurlsession

When I use the `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` API on `NSURLSession`, do I have to keep a strong reference to the task I get back so it doesn't get deallocated before completing, or will the system hold onto it until it completes?

For example, is this OK:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:myRequest completionHandler:
  ^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *err)
  {
    //do something with the response / data / error
  }] resume];
```

Or do I have to do something like this:

```
//assume self.task is a retained property, and is set to nil in dealloc
self.task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:myRequest completionHandler:
  ^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *err)
  {
    //do something with the response / data / error
  }];

[self.task resume];
```

I have code running in production with the first approach and am seeing no crashes because of it, but it's possible that it's sometimes silently failing because the task gets collected by the autorelease pool before it completes and thus never calls my completion block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session [retains the tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html) inside it until after the task completes (including calling any completion handlers).  There's no need to retain it yourself.

Comment: Where in that documentation link do you see this? I don't see any explicit reference to retaining or releasing tasks.

Comment: Important: The session object keeps a strong reference to the delegate until your app explicitly invalidates the session. If you do not invalidate the session, your app leaks memory.

Comment: I know it's there, because I wrote that.  :-)

Comment: Oh, wait, this is about the tasks.  It *did* say that at one time.  I'll look for it.

Comment: Nope.  Can't find it.  Please file a bug against the documentation.  It does, in fact, retain its tasks.

Comment: This is now one of my favorite SO answers ever.

Comment: Here is the document for the strong reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession